# How does npm login (npm adduser) work underneath the covers?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'd like to know how `npm login` (a.k.a. `npm adduser`) works exactly underneath the covers.

I believe the `adduser` command's name is a bit misleading, as it doesn't literally add a user on the server side.

I know how to use it (and I'm guessing how it works), but I'm really interested in the inner workings of it, especially what happens on the server side and then how the `npm` client handles it.

Comment: Not sure if you've already seen it, but it may help your understanding to review the [source code for it](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/lib/adduser.js).

Comment: What exactly do you want to know the code behind it or the complete working overview??

Comment: @SachinYadav : A bit of both would help. :)

Comment: @esqew: Thanks for this! I'll have a look! :)